# FFmpeg adding blank frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg, frames

I'm using this command to generate a video given a set of frames and audio:

```
ffmpeg -y -i index%2d.jpg -i audio.mp3 -acodec copy -vcodec mjpeg -s 1680x1050 -aspect 16:9 result.avi
```

It works amazing, the thing is, what if I have a gap in the index?

Or the other way around, I don't have a gap, but WANT a gap, i.e. blanks frames in the output video.

Given this command and either (whatever option is the best) of not gapped images index or gapped to generate a video with a gap?

Example: I have im1.jpg img2.jpg and i want to generate im1.jpg blank, blank im2.jpg (4 frames) IT IS AN EXAMPLE, I DO NOT WANT A 4 FRAMES VIDEO :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By blank if you mean either all black or all white screens, you can just generate those images and use it with other images at slot that you need them!

Comment: I know that is a solution, but is kinda "dirty", I mean if I have 1000 frames, then  5000 "blanks" and then 1000 frames, I have to generate 5000 blanks frames!.
Imagine more!
Is there any solution for this in FFmepg? or walk around?
Thanks

Comment: No generate one blank from and repeat it. Look at these options: http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images